# WslRegisterDistribution failed with error: 0x80040324

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

Whenever I try to install any Linux distro on WSL I get this error:

[WslRegisterDistribution failed with error: 0x80040324
Error: 0x80040324 (null)
Press any key to continue...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vsrru.png)

This is my setup:

[Versione WSL: 0.67.6.0
Versione kernel: 5.15.62.1
Versione WSLg: 1.0.44
Versione MSRDC: 1.2.3401
Versione Direct3D: 1.606.4
Versione DXCore: 10.0.25131.1002-220531-1700.rs-onecore-base2-hyp
versione Windows: 10.0.22621.521](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dhsYm.png)

The Ubuntu distro is not listed in the installed distro:

[wsl --list --all
Sottosistema Windows per Linux non ha distribuzioni installate.
Usare 'wsl.exe --list --online' per elencare le distribuzioni disponibili e 'wsl.exe --install ' per l'installazione.
È anche possibile installare le distribuzioni visitando il Microsoft Store: https://aka.ms/wslstore
Error code: Wsl/WSL_E_DEFAULT_DISTRO_NOT_FOUND[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJvSp.png)

Anyway if I try to install Ubuntu I get this message:

[wsl --install -d Ubuntu
Ubuntu è già installato. (Ubuntu is alreday installed)
Avvio di Ubuntu in corso...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2AhUd.png)

An then I get this message:

[Installing, this may take a few minutes...
WslRegisterDistribution failed with error: 0x80040324
Error: 0x80040324 (null)
Press any key to continue...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jwr6T.png)

and here it stops.

[Hyper-V is installed without adding any virtual machine or virtual switch in the control panel.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ENHnS.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/msJnb.png)

Is someone having any clue?

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 3):

##### TLDR:

Ensure that you don't have `.wslconfig` and `.wslgconfig` already stored at `C:/Users/{username}` when you start WSL for the first time.

##### More Detail:

I had `.wslconfig` and `.wslgconfig` already stored at `C:/Users/{username}` because I re-installed Windows with "Keep files only" setting. So the files were kept at the same location after the installation. Seems like the initial WSL startup was affected by those configs. As soon as I removed them, distro installation was successful without any reboot required.

`.wslconfig` (at the time of installing WSL):

```ini
[wsl2]
networkingMode = bridged
vmSwitch = WSL Bridge
ipv6 = true
dhcp = false
kernelCommandLine = sysctl.net.ipv6.conf.default.autoconf=0
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

I needed to uninstall WSL, Hyper-V and the Hypervisor platform from Windows Programs & Features, reboot, reinstall everything and then apply the updates from Windows Update.

Answer (score 0):

I had same error message when i tried to install linux sub system in window.

search for "Turn Windows features on or off"
in windows Features popup you can see Windows Subsystem for Linux is uncheck. just the box and click on apply. It will install the necessary packages and will ask for restart now select now.

then try to reinstall Linux distro on WSL it will work fine.